# In Spring/Hibernate/MySql, is autocommit true or false by default?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, transactions, autocommit

I'm using a Amazon RDS MySql 5.5.37 server with another RDS read replica, mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar, Spring 4.3.8.RELEASE and Hibernate 5.1.5.Final.  I have my SPring/Hibernate configuration as such

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.mainco.subco" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap" ref="jpaPropertyMap" />
</bean>

<util:map id="jpaPropertyMap">
    <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
    <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
    <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
    <entry key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />
    <entry key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>
    <entry key="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider"/>
    <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="${enable.hibernate.second_level.cache}" />
    <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="${enable.hibernate.query.cache}" />
    <entry key="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false" />
    <entry key="hibernate.event.merge.entity_copy_observer" value="allow" />
    <entry key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true" />
</util:map>

<bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS" id="dataSource" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

and below is how I set up my datasource in JBoss ...

```
        <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS" pool-name="MySqlDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:mysql:replication://cidb-aurora-cluster.cluster-dbserver.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306,cidb-aurora-read.dbserver.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/dbsid?failOverReadOnly=true</connection-url>
            <driver>mysql</driver>
            <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
            <pool>
                <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                <prefill>true</prefill>
            </pool>
            <security>
                <user-name>username</user-name>
                <password>password</password>
            </security>
            <statement>
                <prepared-statement-cache-size>32</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
            </statement>
        </datasource>
        <drivers>
            <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver</driver-class>
            </driver>
            <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
        </drivers>
```

In my Java code, I mark my transactional service methods with the

```
org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
```

annotation.  My question is, is autocommit enabled or disabled in as far as I haven't specified it?  The next question is, what *should* the value be for autoCommit (true or false)?

Comment: By default hibernate autoCommit mode is set false, here is pretty good article that i think should answer your questions on the subject: https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/Non-transactionalDataAccessAndTheAuto-commitMode

Comment: I'm seeing some things that idnicate this isn't true for the setup I've posted above.  How do I verify what you are saying with my setup?

Comment: At my knowledge (but i'm not an expert) there is nothing that indicate it on the hibernate level. Did you try to manually set the property to false? Plus what make you think it's not true?